# PC will not post to BIOS, replaced everything

Tags: boot, cpu, bios, motherboard, desktop-computer

I need help figuring out why my PC will not post to bios. Newly built PC will not post to BIOS. When I turn it on, it only has a black screen. CPU fan powers up.

What I have done so far.

1. I've removed any miscellaneous components. All that is plugged in now is 1 stick of RAM, CPU, and the PSU.
2. Thinking that one part must be faulty, I have replaced each, one by one to try to isolate the problem. I first thought it was the RAM. Replaced it. Then I thought it was the PSU, replaced. Then the CPU, replaced. Then the mobo, replaced.  Yes, I have literally replaced the entire initial PC (call it PC "A"), no part is the initial now, still no post.
3. I have assembled the PC outside the case on a wooden table to ensure no short.
4. Both mobo have onboard video. I have tried each video port, no post.
5. I have tried inserting a PCIE GPU.
6. I have tried an alternative monitor and video cables (thinking it was my monitor), no post.
7. I have replaced the CPU fan, no post.
8. I have verified that mobo is compatible with RAM and CPU in both PC A and PC B. There is the possibility that the AB350 mobo in PC A does not have updated BIOS to support the Ryzen 5 3600, since the 3600 CPU came out after its manufacturing.
9. Gigabyte's RAM/Memory support list does not officially state that the AB350 mobo is compatible with version 3.31 RAM.
10. AB350 mobo states that support for 3000mhz RAM is CPU dependent. I have verified that the Ryzen 5 3600 is compatible with the 3000mhz RAM.
11. I have tried each of the sticks ( have 4 total) in each of the RAM slots on both mobo. Thinking I either had a bad stick or a bad RAM slot. Still no post.
12. I have pulled out the CPU from its socket, verified no bent pins, ensured it was seated properly and that the heatsink is on properly.
13. I do not plug in the power switch to the either mobo (in case a short). I just power it up by shorting the PWR leads on the mobo. No reset, HDD LED, PWR LED pins are hooked hooked up.
14. I have cleared the BIOS/CMOS. I have replaced the CR2032 button battery with a brand new on in both PC A and PC B.

PC "A"
Gigabyte GA-AB350 Gaming (not "Gaming 3") version 1.0
Ryzen 5 3600 (call this CPU A)
Corsair DDR4 CMK16GX4M2B3000C15 version 5.30 (2 sticks total)
Corsair RM650 PSU

PC "B"
Gigabyte B550M DS3H version 1.5
Ryzen 5 3600 (call this CPU B)
Corsair DDR4 CMK16GX4M2B3000C15 version 3.31 (2 sticks total)
Silverstone SFX ST30SF 300W

I have on hand a GPU MSI RTX 2060 OC. But do not have it plugged in. I have plugged into yet another, older Intel PC (call this PC "C") and verified that the graphics card and Silverstone PSU, and Corsair PSU work.

I am really at a loss. When I finally replaced the last component and basically built PC "B", I thought it would post. I am going crazy since now there is nothing original, other than the CPU heatsink. What in the world is going on?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Both Mobo state they support an onboard graphics. I assumed that this meant that the mobo has onboard graphics. It sounds like this is a wrong assumption.  I'll report back.

Comment: Ryzen 5 3600 does not have integrated Graphics. The HDMI out ports on mobo do not mean there's onboard graphics. On AM4 they are meant for CPU with integrated GPU like Ryzen G series. You must test every combination with Discrete Graphics Card plugged in.

Comment: @ Joshua Smith - I just re-entered my comment.

Answer (score -1):

I got post! I was assuming that I did not need to use the external GPU. I have now got to post with the B550, CPU A, RAM v. 5.30, and RTX 2060. I have yet to get it to work with the AB350 motherboard and I suspect this is the BIOS version issue.